# why the code works on the test machine but failed on the normal machine?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

when the code run at "putMapping()",the mapping will be created on my test environment,but won't be created on my normal environment ,i'm sure the both version of elastic-search are same ,any one met the problem,thx.
[image]

here is the log of elastic-search in my normal environment
[image]

here is the log of elastic-search in my test environment
[image]

mall_test_mapping is my test document

Comment: it will be great if you can post your code and error message as `formmated text` insted of image.

Comment: there is no error message....

Comment: Can you post logs as a text, not a picture?